# ADO passing an array to SQL statement

Tags: sql, vb6, ado

I'm trying to pass an array directly to a SQL statement. Is it possible to use **MyArray()** **directly**  after the IN keyword instead of **MyAr** ?

```
Dim MyArray() As String
MyArray() = Array("YYYY", "BBB")
MyAr = "'YYYY','BBB'"
Set shiftrecordset = New ADODB.Recordset
strSQL1 = "SELECT * FROM assignements where shiftname in (" & MyArr & ")"
shiftrecordset.Open strSQL1, cn, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not possible. You could write a function to do it instead though.

```
Private Function MakeIN(sArr() As String) As String
Dim i As Long
Dim lUB As Long

lUB = UBound(sArr)

For i = LBound(sArr) To lUB
    MakeIN = MakeIN & "'" & sArr(i) & "'"
    If i < lUB Then MakeIN = MakeIN & ","
Next i
End Function
```